# Def function doesn't return any output even if the correct input is supplied

Tags: python

I'm new in programming, using Python 3.9.
So, I'm doing a simple math program from what I understand on reading and tutorials.

here's the code:

```
print('\n Simple Math ')


def num():

    if choice == 1:
        sum = first_num + second_num
        print('Sum is: ', sum)
    elif choice == 2:
        diff = first_num - second_num
        print('Difference is: ', diff)
    elif choice == 3:
        mul = first_num * second_num
        print('Product is: ', mul)
    elif choice == 4:
        div = first_num / second_num
        print('Quotient is: ', div)


while True:
    print('\n 1. Add: \n 2. Subtract: \n 3. Multiply: \n 4. Divide: \n')
    choice = int(input('Select an operator: '))
    if choice > 4 or choice < 1:
        choice = int(input('Input only valid selection from above! \nSelect again: '))
        first_num = float(input('Enter first number: '))
        second_num = float(input('Enter second number: '))
        num()
    break
```

My problem above is, when I added that "Input only valid selection from above!" portion if the user inputs beyond the number of the selection, it doesn't do anything when I try to input from 1 to 4. But if I input 5, it works good.

I already tried to put the first_num and second_num outside the while loop or above the def, tried to put num() before the while, still gives me an error. I'm doubting the portion "if choice > 4 or choice < 1:" that makes my code returns nothing when entering the right selections. Tho I'm kinda stuck and don't know what to do next.

Appreciate any help...
thanks

*Pardon me, I'm really an absolute beginner...*

Comment: Pass the values to the function as arguments.,

Comment: You have everything inside the `if`.  Look at the statement.  If you enter a legal value, nothing will run.  You need an `else:` after the "Input only valid selection" line.

Comment: There are many basic knowledge issues here. Look up the many tutorials on functions and if statements out there, they're generally much better quality than comments and answers on stackoverflow, and you don't even have to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code was a pretty good start. However, there were a few flaws.

1. you need to pass the variables to use to your `num` function
2. you should individualize the logic for inputting the 3 numbers (I used a separate function here)

Below is a working version.

Now you can try to improve it, for example by adding checks on the first_num/second_num values (let's say forbid 0 i second_num for division). You can also try to move the checks into the `validate_input` function.

```
print('\n Simple Math ')

def num(choice, first_num, second_num):

    if choice == 1:
        sum = first_num + second_num
        print('Sum is: ', sum)
    elif choice == 2:
        diff = first_num - second_num
        print('Difference is: ', diff)
    elif choice == 3:
        mul = first_num * second_num
        print('Product is: ', mul)
    elif choice == 4:
        div = first_num / second_num
        print('Quotient is: ', div)

def validate_input(prompt='?: ', input_type=int):
    while True:
        try:
            return input_type(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print('Incorrect input')

while True:
    print('\n 1. Add: \n 2. Subtract: \n 3. Multiply: \n 4. Divide: \n')
    choice = -1
    while choice > 4 or choice < 1:
        choice = validate_input('Select an operator: ')
    first_num = validate_input('Enter first number: ', float)
    second_num = validate_input('Enter second number: ', float)
    num(choice, first_num, second_num)
```

Comment: this nice... thanks for the insight. Btw, about the "prompt='? '" in validate section, is  this the one that holds the value of input overall?

Comment: This is the default value of the prompt if you can the function without setting one

Answer (score 1):

No need to say pardon, you said you're a beginner, mistakes do happen with advanced coders. You have to pass those numbers in the function to use it. Also in the if condition, it is better to use `while` because, once you put wrong input, it'll show error and then it'll ask for input again. Now even if you put wrong input, it'll accept because it will not check again if it is correct. Try doing this:

```
print('\n Simple Math ')


def num(first_num, second_num):

    if choice == 1:
        sum = first_num + second_num
        print('Sum is: ', sum)
    elif choice == 2:
        diff = first_num - second_num
        print('Difference is: ', diff)
    elif choice == 3:
        mul = first_num * second_num
        print('Product is: ', mul)
    elif choice == 4:
        div = first_num / second_num
        print('Quotient is: ', div)


while True:
    print('\n 1. Add: \n 2. Subtract: \n 3. Multiply: \n 4. Divide: \n')
    choice = int(input('Select an operator: '))
    while choice > 4 or choice < 1:
        choice = int(input('Input only valid selection from above! \nSelect again: '))
    first_num = float(input('Enter first number: '))
    second_num = float(input('Enter second number: '))
    num(first_num,second_num)
    break
```

Comment: thanks for this... looks like while is better since every time I use if, I'm always stuck on how am I supposed to loop it back when the input is invalid...

Comment: Exactly. If will check the condition only once, while will check everytime you enter input